# Comparison of variable to all other variables in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, similarity

I want to check how close is one variable to all of the other variables in a data frame. I want to do this by counting the times they have the same value for the same row (i.e. same observation). For instance, in the `mtcars` dataset, the variables `gear` and `carb` have 7 observations in which they have the same value in the same row (i.e. same car).

I have tried the following, which yields a `closeness_matrix`. However, the results seem to be non-sensical. Any idea what is not working?

PS: I also tried to use `mapply`, which I guess it would be faster, but it didn’t work so I ended up with the nested `loop`.

MWE:

```
cols_ls <- colnames(mtcars)

closeness_matrix <- matrix(nrow = ncol(mtcars),
                            ncol = ncol(mtcars))

row.names(closeness_matrix) <- cols_ls; colnames(closeness_matrix) <- cols_ls


for (i in 1:length(cols_ls)){

  for (j in i:length(cols_ls)){

    closeness_matrix[i,j] <- sum(duplicated(mtcars[,c(i,j), with = FALSE])==TRUE)

  }
}
```

Comment: `duplicated` does not work this way, it will give you `TRUE` for every row that has the same values in all columns as a row above. In your case simply use `sum(mtcars[, i] == mtcars[, j])`.

Comment: Thanks I was overthinking it!

Comment: not my business, but why do you want to do such a thing? if you have numeric variables, it's a statistical nonsense to compare exact values... you want a correlation matrix instead. Unless your actual data is categorical?

Comment: @agenis I know it doesn't make sense statistically. I have a relatively big table made by compilation of several data sources (some of them manually filled). I want to check there are no duplicates or nearly duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the following will do it (but i'm sure there is a smarter way):

```
closenessFunc<-function(v1,M){
      apply(M, 2, function(x,v2) {
        sum(x==v)
      }, v2=v1)
    }
apply(mtcars, MARGIN = 2, closenessFunc, M=mtcars)
```

output:

```
     mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
mpg   32   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
cyl    0  32    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    8    2
disp   0   0   32  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
hp     0   0    0 32    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
drat   0   0    0  0   32  0    0  0  0    1    0
wt     0   0    0  0    0 32    0  0  0    0    0
qsec   0   0    0  0    0  0   32  0  0    0    0
vs     0   0    0  0    0  0    0 32 19    0    7
am     0   0    0  0    0  0    0 19 32    0    4
gear   0   8    0  0    1  0    0  0  0   32    7
carb   0   2    0  0    0  0    0  7  4    7   32
```

Comment: Why the last argument of `closenessFunc` is `v=v`? I think this offers a clearer notation 

`closenessFunc<-function(v1,M){
                apply(M, 2, function(x,v2) {
                sum(x==v2)
                }, v2=v1)
}`

Comment: Yes, that was a litte confusing. I changed it. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
sum(duplicated(mtcars[,c(i,j), with = FALSE])==TRUE)
```

to

```
sum(mtcars[,i]==mtcars[,j])
```

duplicated function does not work the way you are using it.